# gelatine, cream and alcohol combination

Tags: dessert, cream, alcohol, gelatin

Concerning alcohol flavored panna cotta, other questions I found focus more on how to prevent a cream plus alcohol mixture from splitting but they assume one knows the right amount of gelatine for their mixture.

Although the instructions on the gelatine package say something like "10g for 500ml liquid", for a cream-only pannacotta I believe it is too much and I've found that half is enough. I applied this for a mixture of 50% cream and 50% baileys.

What can be a reason why this amount of gelatine was not enough?

Comment: Can you post the original recipe and your alterations?

Comment: I must admit that there might have been measurement mistakes, so I'm gonna re-try my recipe asap and either post the quantities or delete the question